# Remove push notification support for some time

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am working on a chat app.App supports push notification but when app comes from background to foreground I dont want to receive any push notification because it is causing some issue.Is it possible to stop app from receiving push notification for some time?

Comment: Use BOOL flag where you notification is getting schedules, make it true and false while going background to foreground, simple trick.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following line in this method to remove remote notification

> applicationWillEnterForeground

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   NSLog(@"app will enter foreground");
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

> applicationWillEnterBackground

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
   NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
   [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

> In Swift

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication)
{

     application.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
}
```